# Java unable to read other lines in text file

Tags: java

[Showing my current progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftyon.png)

I am unable to make the program read more than the first line of text in s.dat in this case.

Is there anything that I am missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post code, not images.  We can't copy/paste images into our own editors/ide

Comment: And ... Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Don't post your code only as link since people with similar problems will not be able to find your question and potential solution to their problems (which is kind of main idea of Stack Overflow) based only on that link. And [don't post text as image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    //get the file location
    String filePath = "somefilepath.txt";

    //catch file IO errors
    try {
        //return the contents of the file
        String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath))
    }
```

It will assign to the variable lines an array of all the string lines in the file. Then you can index into that array to get what you need or loop through it.

EDIT: to do it without arrays see this link:

http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/java-read-a-file-line-by-line-code-example/

Comment: For my assignment we have not learned arrays yet so I am unable to use them.. Is there any other way?

Comment: @GeraldLim Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are doing if ..else statement wrong
Either you are returning to function or breaking the loop in both the case you will going to terminate the loop after first execution so that's why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop reads (approximately):

```
while ( more lines ) {
     if ( match ) {
          return;
     } else {
          break;
     }
 }
```

Your loop will never execute more than once.

Remove the `else` clause, and put the `println("Not found");` after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only read the first line as you have placed return in if block and break in else block. It will come out of loop in both the cases.

Remove the return statement from the if block.

Comment: Actually, remove the `break` from the `else` clause; the OP wants to loop until found, not loop when found.

Comment: I removed the break from the else clause at the bottom, however, it now prints out No information found for every station that does not match. how would I prevent the multiple print lines? I thought break was to help print the line only once.

Comment: You don't want an `else` clause at all.  Delete the `break` and move the `println("No information")` to outside (below) the loop.

Answer (score 0):

your else clause is wrong, if the first loop doesn't match, it's immediately exit while and doesn't do anything else.
you should print the statement "Not found .... " after while loop end.

Comment: Thanks for this. I removed the else statement and printed not found after the loop ended. I have another issue with the printing however, 

the distance prints as <<distance:  :0.190 kms>> for example and I am not sure how to remove the colon before 0.190. Any ideas?